# Reason for Ajax Timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

Am getting timeout exception in ajax often eventhough my server is running and network is available. Help me in solving this..

My code looks like

```
J.ajax({
    type        : "POST",//no i18n
    dataType    : 'json',//No I18N
    global      : false,
    timeout     : 15000, 
    url         : "test.do",
    data        : {},
    error       : function(){},
    success     : function(){}
});
```

Comment: Check the network tab when request fails.. Config looks fine..

Comment: You can test if your server is responding to this call using some REST client for browser providing the similar input manually.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server-side file contain a loop that is not being terminated? That might be your problem.

Comment: Is that a guess you you are certain about it ? [[Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)]

Comment: Calculated guess. Because your config looks fine. What else could be the reason that the server doesn't respond in 15 seconds? Unless of course, it is such an intensive operation.

Comment: You should never put your _guesses_ as answers!